# Sql error that I can't figure out

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Can anyone see the error here. PhpMyAdmin tells me I have an error near the where clause.

```
SELECT product.*, category.*,store.*
WHERE
  store.store_id = product.store_id AND
  category.category_id = product.category_id
INNER JOIN store ON store.store_name = 'mens'
INNER JOIN category ON category.category_name = 'rings'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` belongs in the `FROM` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause. The `FROM` clause is missing entirely.

```
SELECT product.*, category.*, store.*
  FROM product, category, store
 WHERE store.store_id = product.store_id AND
       category.category_id = product.category_id AND
       store.store_name = 'mens' AND
       category.category_name = 'rings'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no `FROM` clause in your sql.

```
select product.*, category.*, store.* from product 
inner join ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing up the purpose of your `where` and `on` clauses.

```
SELECT product.*,category.*,store.* 
From Product
INNER JOIN store on store.store_id = product.store_id
inner join category on category.category_id = product.category_id 
where store.store_name= 'mens' and category.category_name = 'rings'
```

Answer (score 2):

Each major clause in a Select query must be in the proper order.

The order is:

```
Select ... [Output fields and expressuions] -- Required
From ...  [list of tables, with joins and join conditions] -- Required
Where [Predicates and filter conditions]  -- Optional
Group By [list of fields/expressns to group results by] -- reqr'd for aggregate queries
Order By [List of fields and expressions to sort results by -- optional
```